# How to do line count of a file in Azure Data Lake Gen2

Tags: python, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

**Question**: On my local machine, I can get line counts of a data file by using following `python` code. How can we do the same when the file is stored in a container, say, `myContainer` in an `Azure Data Lake Gen2` storage?

```
with open('PPPLoanHoldStatus_AprilData.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for count, line in enumerate(fp):
        pass
print('Total Lines', count + 1)
```

**Remark**: When I use the following code in a `notebook` in an `Azure Databricks`, I get the error shown below:

```
with open('abfss://myContainer@myAzureDLGen2.dfs.core.windows.net/MyDataFile.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for count, line in enumerate(fp):
        pass
print('Total Lines', count + 1)
```

**ERROR**:

> No such file or directory: 'abfss://myContainer@myAzureDLGen2.dfs.core.windows.net/MyDataFile.txt'

Comment: Have you mounted the ADLS with databricks ?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula-MT I want to do it without mounting.

Comment: do you want to hive connect if not mount ? if yes , then have you configured the spark config for the cluster where you are using the notebook?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without mounting, you can try **Azure Data Lake credential passthrough**.

To do this you require **Azure Databricks workspace with premium** plan.

**Step-1:**  Receive log identities by running `Set-AzStorageServiceLoggingProperty` command in ADLS.

**Step-2:** This step can be done in two ways. One is **Enabling ADLS credentials passthrough for a High Concurrency cluster** and the other one is Enabling for a **Standard cluster**.

***High Concurrency cluster:***

[image]

[image]

***Standard Cluster:***

Select cluster mode as Standard and enable the passthrough and give the user access from the drop down like below.

[image]

You can do it in any way you want.

After creating the cluster, you can access the ADLS Gen2 files from the notebook of this cluster with the `abfss://` path.

***NOTE:*** 
Please make sure you have **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role for the ADLS and prefer creating a new cluster and avoid the clusters which are setup with the ADLS credentials before.

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough

Comment: it won't work with the `open` function anyway

Comment: I thought the problem was accessing ADLS gen2 from databricks. Thats why I provided the information about that. thanks for letting me know about the main issue. please consider posting about the reason for it if possible.